# How can i change UI using R server?

Tags: html, r, shiny

I create a shiny app that look like this:
[image]

I want that every time that a customer will use this app. it will remember hes last choices.

The way that i want to do this, is using R code in the server. I will save the last choices in a database. And then, when the client will login again i want to insert to each <*div*> his last choice that saved in my database.

My question is: how can i insert using server a select command.

For example in 'Choose industry' the client choose 'Online'. so the next login of the client i want something like this in server: `output$name_of_the_online_input<-Online_Choise`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In server.R, you can use

```
shiny::updateTextInput
```

to modify the values of a textInput displayed in ui.R